# How do I populate an asp dropdownlist with data from an sql database based on the text from an asp textbox using c#?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a small web form that is used to archive jobs. The user puts in the job number in a textbox and then a dropdown needs to be filled with the customers that are bidding the job. The user also chooses whether the job was won or lost or a duplicated. Then they submit the form and the sql database is updated. I can't find and examples of populating a dropdown list based on a textbox. All the examples I find are populating textboxes based on the dropdown.

```
<div class="container">
    <h2>Job Archive Form</h2>
        <div class="form-group">
            <asp:Label ID="lblJobNumber" runat="server">Job Number</asp:Label><br />
            <asp:TextBox ID="archiveJobNumber" runat="server" AutoPostBack="True" OnTextChanged="archiveJobNumber_TextChanged"/>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <asp:Label ID="lblJobStatus" runat="server">Job Status</asp:Label><br />
            <asp:DropDownList ID="archiveJobStatus" runat="server">
                <asp:ListItem value="">--Select--</asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem value="1">Active</asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem value="2">Won</asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem value="3">Lose</asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem value="4">Duplicate</asp:ListItem>
            </asp:DropDownList>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <asp:Label ID="lblCustomer" runat="server">Customer</asp:Label><br />
            <asp:DropDownList ID="archiveCustomer" runat="server" DataSourceID="archiveSqlDSCustomer" DataTextField="Name" DataValueField="CustID" AutoPostBack="True"></asp:DropDownList>
        </div>                                                        
        <asp:Button ID="submit" runat="server" Text="Submit" OnClick="submit_Click"></asp:Button>
</div>
```

Code Behind:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Data;
using System.Configuration;
using System.Web.Security;
using System.Web.UI.HtmlControls;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls.WebParts;
using System.Data.SqlClient;

namespace JobsApp
{
    public partial class Archive : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (Session["UID"] == null)
                Response.Redirect(@"Account\Login.aspx");
        }

        protected void submit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string constring = "";
            constring = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["JobsConstr"].ToString();
            SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(constring);
            con.Open();
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("usp_changeJobStanding", con);
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            SqlParameter jobNumber = cmd.Parameters.Add("@jobNumber", SqlDbType.VarChar);
            SqlParameter jobStanding = cmd.Parameters.Add("@jobStanding", SqlDbType.Int);
            jobNumber.Value = archiveJobNumber.Text;
            jobStanding.Value = archiveJobStatus.Text;
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            con.Close();
            Response.Redirect("~/Archive.aspx");
        }

        protected void archiveJobNumber_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            archiveSqlDSCustomer.SelectCommand = "GetCustomerListByJobNumber";
            archiveCustomer.DataSourceID = "archiveSqlDSCustomer";
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: It looks like you are getting the data based on the textbox value, do you not know how to build up drop down items, or data bind the drop down control?

Comment: @jaz1976 Could you show the code of archiveSqlDSCustomer?

Comment: i don't know how to build the drop down or bind the data. ASP.Net is new to me I usually work with node. I've inherited this from a programmer who left.

Comment: @Win the archiveSqlDSCustomer is nothing. I was trying to follow an incomplete example and I forgot to remove it from the post.

Comment: One other thing I tried was this in the dropdownlist element.  `<%--<asp:SqlDataSource ID="archiveSqlDSCustomer" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:JobsConStr %>" SelectCommand="GetCustomerListByJobNumber" SelectCommandType="StoredProcedure">
                        <SelectParameters>
                            <asp:ControlParameter Name="jobNumber" DbType="String" ControlID="archiveJobNumber" PropertyName="Text" ConvertEmptyStringToNull="false" />
                        </SelectParameters>
                    </asp:SqlDataSource>--%>`I didn't know how to trigger this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could retrieve data from database inside `archiveJobNumber_TextChanged` event, and bind the data to `DropDownList`.

*For example,*

```
<asp:TextBox ID="archiveJobNumber" runat="server" AutoPostBack="True"
    OnTextChanged="archiveJobNumber_TextChanged" />

<asp:DropDownList ID="archiveCustomer" runat="server"
    DataTextField="Name" DataValueField="CustID" AutoPostBack="True">
</asp:DropDownList>


protected void archiveJobNumber_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var query = "SELECT CustID, Name FROM Users WHERE CustID= @Id";
    using (var con = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
    using (var da = new SqlDataAdapter(query, con))
    {
        con.Open();
        var dt = new DataTable();
        da.SelectCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Id", archiveJobNumber.Text);

        da.Fill(dt);
        archiveCustomer.DataSource = dt;
        archiveCustomer.DataBind();
    }
}
```

*Please make sure query is correct.*

Comment: This did work for me. Thank you Win. I modified it a little to use a stored procedure instead of imbedding the sql statement in the code.